# regex grouping doesn't seem to respect nested hierarchy

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these tests string :

```
abc optional def ghi

abc def ghi
```

that both match this regex

```
(.+) ((optional \s*)?def)\s+(.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0pZQEy/1

but I want to group optional with def whereas it groups optional with abc, I can't see how to fix this

Comment: Then use a lazy quantifier, `*` > `*?`.

Comment: ... something like [`(.*?)\s+((?:optional\s+)?def)\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/0pZQEy/2) where `'optional'` indeed would be just an option too?